# mdframed Section Spacing

Tags: sectioning, mdframed

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[framemethod = tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\begin{document} 
    \begin{mdframed}
%       \section*{Objective:}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item To become familiar with the measurements in electric circuits
            \item To determine the equivalent resistances of series and parallel combinations
            \item To use Kirchhoff's laws
        \end{itemize}
    \end{mdframed}
    \begin{mdframed}
        \section*{Objective:}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item To become familiar with the measurements in electric circuits
            \item To determine the equivalent resistances of series and parallel combinations
            \item To use Kirchhoff's laws
        \end{itemize}
    \end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

As we can see, the `section` header produces extra whitespace between itself and the top of the `mdframed` box. How much whitespace does it produce, and how to remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative using a customized box with the help of the `tcolorbox` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}
{
  colback  = white,
  sharp corners, 
  boxrule=1pt
}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\begin{document} 
    \begin{mybox}
%       \section*{Objective:}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item To become familiar with the measurements in electric circuits
            \item To determine the equivalent resistances of series and parallel combinations
            \item To use Kirchhoff's laws
        \end{itemize}
    \end{mybox}
    \begin{mybox}
        \section*{Objective:}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item To become familiar with the measurements in electric circuits
            \item To determine the equivalent resistances of series and parallel combinations
            \item To use Kirchhoff's laws
        \end{itemize}
    \end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So does `\boxrule = 1pt` essentially get rid of the whitespace between `section` and the top?

Comment: On a side note, while the white space on top is gone, more side margins are added within the box i.e. the section moved slightly to the right. I was wondering If there was a way to *only* get rid of the top whitespace, but not change any horizontal spacing between the text and the vertical edges.

Comment: @Superman: `boxrule=1pt` just sets the width of the actual line to 1pt.

Comment: Regarding the horizotal spacing: Probably `\newtcolorbox{mybox}
{
  colback  = white,
  sharp corners, 
  boxrule=1pt, left=2mm, right=2mm
}` is closer to the desired output?

Comment: Looks about it! Thank you!